# Show Bootstrap modal using (#myModal).modal('show') from Angular component

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, bootstrap-4

I have an Angular 8 project that is using bootstrap. I am trying to show the modal dialog inside my component using the `$('myModal').modal('show')` inside my component's *Typescript* file.

Here's my component's file:

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {Router} from '@angular/router';
// import * as $ from 'jquery';
import * as bootstrap from 'bootstrap';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-xyz',
  templateUrl: './xyz.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./xyz.css']
})
export class XyzComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private router: Router) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  submit() {
    $('#confirm').modal('show');
  }

}
```

Upon invoking the submit() funciton on click I get the following error: `ERROR TypeError: $(...).modal is not a function`

I installed bootstrap and jquery using `npm install bootstrap` --save and `npm install jquery --save`.

I even installed *ngx-bootstrap*.

However, when I uncomment the line importing *jQuery* I get a different error: `ERROR TypeError: jquery__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3__(...).modal is not a function`

Comment: you don't import jquery...

Comment: It's better to use angular material dialog. https://material.angular.io/components/dialog

Comment: "better to use angular material dialog"... but he's not using material, he's using bootstrap.

Comment: As you've already installed `ngx-bootstrap` consider using their [modal](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/modals). Try not to mix jQuery and Angular, generally you don't need to.

Answer (score 2):

Check your angular.json file to make sure that the Jquery js file is included in your scripts array.

`"scripts": [
    "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
]`

Then in your component TS file declare var $ instead of trying to import it:

`declare var $: any;`

That should allow you to trigger the modal via

`$('#confirm').modal();`

Also make sure that the HTML is correct. Example Modal:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="confirm" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" data-backdrop="static" aria-labelledby="noDataModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header" style="background-color:lightgrey">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="noDataModalLongTitle">No Data</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <i class="fas fa-check fa-4x mb-3 animated rotateIn"></i>
                No Data Found. Please expand your search criteria and try again.
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Ok</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

- You need to add bootstrap to your angular.json scripts
- You need to have [bootstrap types](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/bootstrap) installed

[My solution is live here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ts-bootstrap-k9n6dm?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

YOUR_COMPONENT_NAME.component.html

```
<button (click)="submit()">Submit</button>

<div #yourSelectorName class="modal" tabindex="-1">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Modal body text goes here.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

=========================

YOUR_COMPONENT_NAME.component.ts

```
import { Component, ElementRef, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import * as bootstrap from 'bootstrap';

export class <your-component-name>Component {
 @ViewChild('yourSelectorName') modalRef = {} as ElementRef;

 submit() {
  const modal = new bootstrap.Modal(this.modalRef.nativeElement)
  modal.show()
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To access/control the Bootstrap 5 modal via the ***.component.ts** file in angular follow the below points:

1. Add import

`import { Modal } from 'bootstrap';`

2. Create a new instance of the modal in ***.component.html** for referencing via ***.component.ts** file eg I am trying to show the edit task modal which has `id='edit-task-modal'`

`const editTaskModal = new Modal('#edit-task-modal');`

3. All done!! just use it now as per your requirements eg showing/hiding the modal

`editTaskModal.show()`

For more info you can refer to the latest bootstrap docs as of now: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/components/modal/#via-javascript

**P.S**: There is no direct relation between [bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/) & [ngx-bootstrap](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/) they both are 2 different libraries.

## Update

After using the above method, some of the dropdown across our whole application seems to not work properly (either just by importing or creating new instance), so as of now due to time constraints I will not continue to dig deep into why it happened or how its related. continuing now with an alternate approach

**create a hidden field, and just simply call the click() function.**

```html
<input
    type="hidden"
    data-bs-toggle="modal"
    data-bs-target="#work-schedule-edit-task-modal"
    id="work-schedule-edit-task-modal-toggler" />
```

```js
const workScheduleEditTaskModalTogglerNativeElement = document.getElementById('work-schedule-edit-task-modal-toggler');

if (workScheduleEditTaskModalTogglerNativeElement) {
    workScheduleEditTaskModalTogglerNativeElement.click();
}
```

Thank you.